# ggplot2 remove nonsignificant zeros

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a barplot that I've flipped the coordinates and stacked as a proportional bar I'd like to change the y scale (now in the x scale position) to not have non significant zeros:

My attempt:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill=cut)) + 
    geom_bar(position='fill') + coord_flip() +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1), 
        labels=c("0", ".25", ".5", ".75", "1"))
```

Current plot:
[image]

Comment: what are non-significant zeroes here?

Comment: @Maiasaura I want `0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 and 1.00` to become `0, .25, .50, .75 and 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, it works with `scale_y_continuous`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, fill=cut)) +
 geom_bar(position='fill') +
 coord_flip() +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1),
                    labels=c("0", ".25", ".5", ".75", "1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  In retrospect what was I thinking with discrete?